# Jetty server always pointing to default 'root' user of a Mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, jetty

I am using MySQL database and Jetty server for my project. I have created a non root user in MySQL. When trying to access this non root user with the below code , Jetty always trying to login as root user and I am getting **access denied error.**

Entry in my

**database.properties**

```
username=AMUser
password=am@123
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/AMDB
```

The below **configuration xml** is using to read the properties

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="${url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${password}" />
    </bean>
```

**property place holder configuration in application context**

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">  
             <property name="locations" >
                    <list>
                          <value>file:/home/database.properties</value>
                   </list>  
             </property>                
             </bean>
```

Comment: can you share exact error message you get fgrom DB?

Comment: 07-12-2015 17:33:07,012 WARN  - SQL Error: 1045, SQLState: 28000
07-12-2015 17:33:07,012 ERROR - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Sorry but a stacktrace might help more - how does it come there? Is there maybe more than 1 database.properties at different locations? Do you have any other place where create a connection?